# Sencha Architect 3.2. Why are buttons sending 2 click events?

Tags: events, extjs, click

I'm building a web based application using Extjs in Sencha architect.  I've been building apps with this tool for nearly 7 years so I'm familiar with the tool and the architecture.  But now, every button is sending 2 click events.  I've added a simple button with the id 'testButton'

```
      {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'south',
            id: 'KPIWindowStatusBarPanel',
            margin: '0 5 5 5',
            manageHeight: false,
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'top',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'tbfill'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'testButton',
                            itemId: 'testButton',
                            text: 'TestButton'
                        },
and so on
```

My controller is mapped normally

```
    control: {
        "#testButton": {
            click: 'onTestButtonClick'
        }
and so on
```

The actual function is just a console.log()

```
    onTestButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        console.log('test button click');

    },
```

But Firebug shows that this, and every other button is sending 2 click events every time they are pressed.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  I've never seen this before in any of our other apps.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any problems. You have to look somewhere else, maybe you double click?

Take a look on example on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/356g

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.controller.ButtonController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    control: {
        "#testButton": {
            click: 'onTestButtonClick'
        }
    },

    onTestButtonClick: function (button, e, eOpts) {
        console.log('test button click');

    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    controllers: ['ButtonController'],
    launch: function () {

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            height: 200,
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'tbfill'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'testButton',
                    itemId: 'testButton',
                    text: 'TestButton'
                }]
            }],
            width: 250,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: No, i'm certainly not double clicking.  And I have done the trick where the click event code disables the button when it's called to avoid double clicks.

Comment: Maybe you override something in base classes like `Ext.button.Button`?

Comment: Nope, it's just a standard app with no overriding.

Comment: Maybe control is fired twice because, button is part of tools, that have its own click event. To diagnose these look for click event arguments. If they are different than thats the problem. To overcome this problem, you could just use handler property of button that would only allow tools item click event to be registered, not of a button

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense, and I will add it to the list of reasons I should move away from Sencha Architect and ExtJS and over to Angular JS.  I've lost count of how many times we've had impossible problems with an app built in Sencha Architect over the past 7 years.

I had 2 controllers.  My main controller, and a 2nd controller called KPIController just to handle all the functions in this specific panel.  I had a "loadData" function which loads data into a grid panel in the KPIControler.  When I moved that method out of my KPIController and into the MainController all the buttons started sending single clicks again.

It makes no sense at all.